# Swift 360 image: How i can add a button in a panoramic image

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal, 360-panorama

I have an image, I convert it into a 360 panoramic image, using metal (https://github.com/ejeinc/MetalScope). How can I add a button on the door [(see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZXU1.png)  so that by clicking on it, it would go to the next controller with a different panoramic image (another room)

github project : https://github.com/Mahnach/MetalRender

Comment: Did you get solution of this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: @EvgenyMahnach have you got any solution for this particular requirement??

Answer (score -1):

You can add a tap gesture recogniser to the image, then get the point where image is tapped. If it is tapped near the door, perform segue to the next controller. If you're not sure where the door area is, you can print out the touch point & see where on the image you're tapping.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create Tap Gesture
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction(_:)))

    //Enable image user interaction
    self.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //Add Tap gesture to the image
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    //Get the touch point
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.imageView)

    //Set the door area
    let doorArea = CGRect(x: 200.0, y: 100.0, width: 75.0, height: 100.0)

    //Then check if touch point is near door
    if doorArea.contains(touchPoint){
        //Peform segue
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextScene", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a panoramic image, it has scrolling, with a different viewing angle, the button should be visible or not visible

Comment: It should be visible or it won't register touches. It shouldn't matter if its a panoramic image the code above should still work.

Comment: I mean, this button will always be in one place on the screen, but should change the location depending on the panoramic image scrolling

Comment: Ah ok, well you can use the scroll view delegate to check how much the user has scrolled the image and then use this as an offset for the door button. So if the user has scrolled 50 pixels to the right, just take this away from the touch point calculation.